# In Python, pandas, how to ignore invalid values in python when i convert the columns from hexa to decimal?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

when I use:

```
df[["Type 2", "Type 4"]].applymap(lambda n: int(n, 16))
```

It stops in the error because of invalid value in Type 2 column because of invalid values (negative values, NaN, string...) for hexa conversion. how to ignore this error or mark the invalid value as zero

```
{'Type 1': {0: 1, 1: 3, 2: 5, 3: 7, 4: 9, 5: 11, 6: 13, 7: 15, 8: 17},
         'Type 2': {0: 'AA',
          1: 'BB',
          2: 'NaN',
          3: '55',
          4: '3.14',
          5: '-96',
          6: 'String',
          7: 'FFFFFF',
          8: 'FEEE'},
         'Type 3': {0: 0, 1: 0, 2: 0, 3: 0, 4: 0, 5: 0, 6: 0, 7: 0, 8: 0},
         'Type 4': {0: '23',
          1: 'fefe',
          2: 'abcd',
          3: 'dddd',
          4: 'dad',
          5: 'cfe',
          6: 'cf42',
          7: '321',
          8: '0'},
         'Type 5': {0: -120,
          1: -120,
          2: -120,
          3: -120,
          4: -120,
          5: -120,
          6: -120,
          7: -120,
          8: -120}}
```

Comment: What do you want the output to look like?

Answer (score 2):

You can create a personalized function that handles this exception to use in your lambda. For example:

```py
def lambda_int(n):
    try:
        return int(n, 16)
    except ValueError:
        return 0

df[["Type 2", "Type 4"]] = df[["Type 2", "Type 4"]].applymap(lambda n: lambda_int(n))
```

Comment: It works, but how to retain the column order same as initial... as this way discards the rest of the columns

Comment: I edited it to update the columns on df without removing the other ones

Answer (score 0):

Please go through this, i reconstructed your question and gave steps to follow

```
1. You first dictionary you provided does not have a value, it has a string "NaN"
data = {'Type 1': {0: 1, 1: 3, 2: 5, 3: 7, 4: 9, 5: 11, 6: 13, 7: 15, 8: 17},
         'Type 2': {0: 'AA',
          1: 'BB',
          2: 'NaN',
          3: '55',
          4: '3.14',
          5: '-96',
          6: 'String',
          7: 'FFFFFF',
          8: 'FEEE'},
         'Type 3': {0: 0, 1: 0, 2: 0, 3: 0, 4: 0, 5: 0, 6: 0, 7: 0, 8: 0},
         'Type 4': {0: '23',
          1: 'fefe',
          2: 'abcd',
          3: 'dddd',
          4: 'dad',
          5: 'cfe',
          6: 'cf42',
          7: '321',
          8: '0'},
         'Type 5': {0: -120,
          1: -120,
          2: -120,
          3: -120,
          4: -120,
          5: -120,
          6: -120,
          7: -120,
          8: -120}}

import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df.head()
```

[image]

2. To check nan in your df and remove them

   columns_with_na = df.isna().sum()
   #filter starting from 1 missing value
   columns_with_na = columns_with_na[columns_with_na != 0]
   print(len(columns_with_na))
   print(len(columns_with_na.sort_values(ascending = False))) #print them in descendng order

Prints 0 and 0 because there is no nan

3. Reconstructed your data to include a nan by using numpy.nan

   import numpy as np

   ```
    #recreated a dataset and included a nan value : np.nan at Type 2
    data = {'Type 1': {0: 1, 1: 3, 2: 5, 3: 7, 4: 9, 5: 11, 6: 13, 7: 15, 8: 17},
             'Type 2': {0: 'AA',
              1: 'BB',
              2: np.nan,
              3: '55',
              4: '3.14',
              5: '-96',
              6: 'String',
              7: 'FFFFFF',
              8: 'FEEE'},
             'Type 3': {0: 0, 1: 0, 2: 0, 3: 0, 4: 0, 5: 0, 6: 0, 7: 0, 8: 0},
             'Type 4': {0: '23',
              1: 'fefe',
              2: 'abcd',
              3: 'dddd',
              4: 'dad',
              5: 'cfe',
              6: 'cf42',
              7: '321',
              8: '0'},
             'Type 5': {0: -120,
              1: -120,
              2: -120,
              3: -120,
              4: -120,
              5: -120,
              6: -120,
              7: -120,
              8: -120}}

    df2 = pd.DataFrame(data)

    df2.head()
   ```

[image]

```
    #sum up number of columns with nan
    columns_with_na = df2.isna().sum()
    #filter starting from 1 missing value
    columns_with_na = columns_with_na[columns_with_na != 0]
    print(len(columns_with_na))
    print(len(columns_with_na.sort_values(ascending = False)))
```

prints 1 and 1 because there is a nan at Type 2 column

```
#drop nan values
df2 = df2.dropna(how = 'any')

#sum up number of columns with nan
columns_with_na = df2.isna().sum()
#filter starting from 1 missing value
columns_with_na = columns_with_na[columns_with_na != 0]
print(len(columns_with_na))
```

#prints 0 because I dropped all the nan values

```
df2.head()
```

[image]

5. To fill nan in df with 0 use:

   df2.fillna(0, inplace = True)
6. Fill in nan with 0 in df2['Type 2'] only:

   #if you dont want to change the origina dataframe set inplace to false

   ```
    df2['Type 2'].fillna(0, inplace = True) #inplace is set to True to change the original df
   ```